# Mekor for R' Haim on Tannaim vs Amoraim

Tags: sources-mekorot, machlokes, tannaim, amoroim, chaim-soloveitchik

I've heard that R' Haim Soloveitchik said that although there is no law stating that  Amoraim may not argue with Tannaim, nevertheless it isn't customary for an Amora to contradict a Tanna. Does anyone know the source to this?

Comment: I think the Kesef Mishnah says this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Kovetz Shiurim (Bava Basra 633).

(The book Torah Chazal and Science quotes the R. Elchonon citing R. Chaim. I imagine then that it isnt in any of R. Chaim's sfarim.)